# Intuit IPP AggCat - 102 Retry error

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

We have some '102 Retry' errors with our Intuit IPP AggCat for a particular financial institution when trying to discover and add accounts.

This error seems to be related to the financial institution, but their web site works well.

Is there a way to solve this issue with IPP AggCat webservices ?

Answer (score 0):

Please submit a support ticket to IPP with the institution details.